# Most efficient way to control a C++ instance through Lua?

Tags: c++, lua

I'm currently coding a game in C++ with cocos2d-x, which comes bundled with tolua++, so I wanted to take advantage of that and have some functionalities be in Lua scripts. Eventually I'd like to expand how many functionalities will be controlled by script, but for now I'm just trying to have Lua scripts for enemy behavior, which seems like a good place to start.

Each enemy has a C++ Entity instance associated with it. As the game stands now, each enemy performs its behavior calculations on update(), but I'd like to change that so each enemy has a script or script function that represents its behavior, and that gets called on update(). I've come to the conclusion that there's essentially two ways of accomplishing this:

1. Have one global function for each behavior, as pass the enemy instance as a parameter
2. Have all enemy instances be tracked on Lua's side with a reference (or an instance ID) on the C++ side

I've already worked out how to implement solution #1. Here's my test:

C++:

```c
lua_getglobal(L, "printNodePosition");
tolua_pushusertype(L, pNode, "CCNode");
lua_call(L, 1, 0);
```

Lua:

```lua
function printNodePosition(n)
    n:setPosition(66, 99)
    print ("Node position: " .. n:getPositionX() .. ", " .. n:getPositionY())
end
```

This works fine, the node position value gets altered as expected. However I can't help by feel that this seems a little bit hacky, and that maybe this could cause a serious overhead (there can be up to 50 enemies on screen at any time, each one of them calling the script on every tick.)

Solution #2 seems a bit more appropriate, but I can't figure out how to implement it. What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you handling most of your logic, and what is it generally doing? Are you doing anything that couldn't be done in Lua, in C++, or vice versa?

Comment: The great majority of it will be C++ (right now it's all C++ since I've just started integrating Lua.) My plan is exposing some stuff to Lua (such as enemy behavior, or perhaps scripting cinematic sequences) so that the Game Designer can contribute too, also to facilitate testing and tweaking of stuff without having to recompile every time.

Comment: I think this depends a bit on how your game engine is designed and how much control you want exposed to lua. I'd imagine you already have individual entitles tracked to some capacity in the engine. How about providing some interface for lua to query for live game entities? You could have it filter by some given criteria to help focus the query.

Answer (score 3):

How you decide to handle this will largely depend on a sort of *division of labor* if you will. You will need to set clear and precise boundaries on who's taking care of what, otherwise you'll end up duplicating information on both sides, or worse. *Some* logic handled with C++, yet *some other* logic handled with Lua, but it isn't clear what divides the two.

Why track them on Lua's side, when they could ***be*** in Lua? If you're interested in expanding how much control Lua has over your engine, then all the better. Now's a good time to start moving over your data and logic.

I feel that this problem comes up because there are things that both C++ and Lua can handle, obviously, but it's not immediately clear which should handle what. I propose the following division, and I'd like you to tell me what you think.

#### C++

- Graphics
- Audio
- Networking
- Functions which need to be more efficient but can't be made any better in Lua.

#### Lua

- Everything else

To summarize this, keep a strict limit on having C++ handle things Lua couldn't do intrinsically, like platform-dependent features such as graphics, and let Lua take care of the rest. The one exception being that you find a critical point in your engine which *absolutely* must be made faster, and offload it to C++.

Imagine as if Lua is the main language where C/C++ libraries fill in the gaps, essentially.

That said, this may not be the best solution for all programs requiring scripting, but I think it's a decent one for your case of a game engine.

---

That aside, I'd like to share a [rant](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.lua.general/84483) written by the developer of LuaJIT on the topic of [*Design mistakes in mixed C/C++ and Lua projects*](http://news.gmane.org/find-root.php?group=gmane.comp.lang.lua.general&article=84483) in response to the scenario of `1. Not truly choosing a language to implement the project in (eg., too much mixing between the 2 languages).`

Comment: Loved the rant, funny thing is that the "Our games will NEVER need scripting" part is pretty much how I thought just a few months ago. That's also to say that I'm very very new to Lua, and I'm also the only programmer on this project, which is running late already, so I'd be very reluctant to rewrite the stuff I already have in C++ to Lua. I have a lot to learn still, so I'll probably have the next project be more Lua-intensive, but for this one (which won't be that big of a project anyway) I want to stick to having scripts for just a few things.